# didn't find class scrollview on path dexpathlist

Tags: android

I'm building my first app on android. I'm getting an error "didn't find class scrollview on path dexpathlist". Can you help me?

Here is my main.xml:

```
    <scrollview xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <linearlayout
        android:id="@+id/widget1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <textview
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" >

            <com.example.horizontal_spinner
                android:id="@+id/spiner"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp" >

                <textview
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="---" >
                </textview>
            </com.example.horizontal_spinner>
        </textview>
    </linearlayout>

</scrollview>
```

and my manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.horizontalspinner"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.horizontalspinner.HorizontalSpinnerActivity"
            android:label="Spinner" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I launch the task I get only an "Unfortunately your app has stopped." Looking my logcat I can't find the problem.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple: the tag is wrong, must be `ScrollView` not `scrollview`

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        tools:context=".DetailActivity$PlaceholderFragment">
```